# Extracting passing year from resume

Tags: python

I have written logic to extract the passing year from the resume. I extract degree using lookup of degree list.

Here is the link for text and code - https://github.com/karimkhanp/resumeparser

After having all degrees in CV I do line split and checking each line. If any degree present in any line then check if is there any 4 digit number starting with 19 or 20 in the same line. Consider it a year.

Logic code:

```
def get_passingyear(self, text, education):
    text_lines = text.splitlines()
    passing_year = []
    for line in text_lines:
        for degree in education:
            if degree in line:
                year = re.findall('\b(19|20)\d{2}\b', text)
                p_year = {}
                if len(year) > 1:
                    year = '-'.join(year)
                    p_year[degree]= year
                    break
                else:
                    p_year[degree]= year
                    break
```

Is there any better way to write this code? I have added `break` to exit the loop if the year of the degree is fetched.

I appreciate it is there any better logic for the same

Comment: it would be better if you posted or shared a link to the input text

Comment: I shared link @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: share the link to the concrete file, not the bunch of arbitrary files

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: I dont have issue with any specific file. I want to validate the logic and code I have written. Is there any better python function for the same activity to make code look better.

Comment: I hope these persons are either not real or you have their permission to publish their personal data!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EAFP principle and give it a try with the datetime module:

```
import datetime

....

        if degree in line:
            try:
                year = re.findall('\b(19|20)\d{2}\b', text)
                # Try to make a date out of it
                datetime.date(year=int(year))
            except TypeError:
                # if it is not a date, you can treat it here
                pass

            ....
```

This way you won't risk to get something that is not a year
And if all your dates foolow a pattern in those files, you can use strptime from [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) to get the date from this pattern